# Flask: Using same template in a page for multiple times

Tags: python, templates, flask

Using the following code I want to show the contents of two items from two dataframe in the index page. I know how to do that for item1, but don't know how to use the same template for item 2 to show item 2 below item 1 in the page.

```
    item1 = get_item(df1,item_index)
    item2 = get_item(df2,item_index)
    return render_template(
        "item.html",
        dfname=Path(dfname1).stem,
        data=item1,
        total=len(df1),
        prev_status="disabled" if item_index == 0 else "",
        next_status="disabled" if item_index == len(df1) - 1 else "",
        item_index=item_index,
    )
```

Comment: `data=item2` ? ... its not really very clear what you are asking to me

Comment: @JoranBeasley I clarfied that I want to show both in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Pass both. Then use them in your html using jinja,

```
data1 = item1
data2 = item2
```

Am i missing something in your question?

**Update after 1st comment.
In your html, you may use

```
{{data1}}
{{data2}}
```

to access the items.

If you are displaying them in a table or sequentially, you may even use the for loop. Giving you a hint on it:

```
{% for row in data1 %} 
<tr>                                                                
    <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
    <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
    <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
    <td>{{row[3]}}%</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Similarly for data2

Comment: So please tell me what to do in that template, I am new to Flask or jinja. I myself think I must pass them as a list

Comment: Updated the answer. Reading a few more online resources on using jinja might be a good thought.

Comment: I tried `{% for data in items %}` in template and passed `items=[item1, item2]` to it, however it only show one of them.

Comment: Please post your complete code including the html part. Will be easier to get the problem. Also, the structure of item1 and item2 and what are you trying to display.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, the problem was solved. however your answer is not correct or complete, please modify it so I vote it up and accept it. You should pass two items as a list, and then use a loop to render them.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `for` in the template and pass both items to it.

```
item1 = get_item(df1,item_index)
item2 = get_item(df2,item_index)
return render_template(
    "item.html",
    dfname=Path(dfname1).stem,
    data=[item1, item2],
    total=len(df1),
    prev_status="disabled" if item_index == 0 else "",
    next_status="disabled" if item_index == len(df1) - 1 else "",
    item_index=item_index,
)
```

And in template:

```
  {% for item in data %}
     <p> {{ item.something }} </p>
     ...
  {% endfor %}
```